# Multiple foreach in Durandal

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, foreach, durandal

I am all new to Durandal and have been playing around with it for a few hours now. It seems very promising - but now I have run into a problem, I cannot figure out - and cannot find a solution with Google.

I have a view with three tables of data - creditCardLines, cashLines and drivingReimbursementLines. They fetch data from three different data sources - and the user can add new lines to cashLines and drivingReimbursementLines (left out the forms).

Problem: In the viewmodel, I can easily bind a list for data to the first foreach - but I cannot figure out how to bind data to the second and third.

In the activate function I make an ajax call to my server API to get the data for the first foreach - and then returns the promise, when this finishes. How do I get data for the second and third foreach here?

ViewModel:

```
define(function () {
    var submit = function () {
        this.displayName = 'Expenses';

        this.creditCardLines = ko.observableArray();
        var me = this;

        this.activate = function () {
            return $.get('/submit/GetCreditCardLines').then(function (creditCardLines) {
                me.creditCardLines(creditCardLines.Data);
            });
        };
    };

    return submit;
});
```

View:

```
<section>
    <h2 data-bind="html:displayName"></h2>

    <h3>CreditCard lines</h3>
    <table class="table">
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: creditCardLines">
            <tr>
                <td class="date" data-bind="text: Date"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Description"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Amount"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: ApprovedEmployee" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <h3>Cash lines</h3>
    <table class="table">
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: cashLines">
            <tr>
                <td class="date" data-bind="text: Date"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Description"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Amount"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- TODO: Generate form to add new lines -->

    <h3>Driving reimbursement lines</h3>
    <table class="table">
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: drivingReimbursementLines">
            <tr>
                <td class="date" data-bind="text: Date"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Description"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Distance"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Rate"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Amount"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- TODO: Generate form to add new lines -->

    <!-- Approve and save all lines as a quote with lines -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit quote" />
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I've been dealing with multiple jQuery deferred calls in my view models:

```
return $.when(
        $.get('/submit/GetCreditCardLines'),
        $.get('/submit/GetCashLines'),
        $.get('/submit/GetReimbursementLines'))
    .then(function (creditCardLines, cashLines, reimbursementLines)
    {
        processCreditCardLines(creditCardLines);
        processCashLines(cashLines);
        processReimbursementLines(reimbursementLines);
    })
    .fail(function (status)
    {
        // Do whatever you need to if it fails
    });
```

You don't need the process methods if you don't want them, but if you're doing anything complicated, I think it's neater to have them.

Comment: Could you set it up so that each "process" method is chained to its corresponding $.get with `then` - instead of combining them into a single `then`?

Comment: You can, but if you do it this way, all three calls are fired off at the same time, and it processes the then when all three are back, so it should, in theory, be quicker. I've actually only just changed my code to do it this way rather than chaining the requests! But yes, you can chain them if you wish.

Comment: I see.  What I was thinking of was to chain it like this:  `return $.when( $.get().then(), $.get().then(), $.get().then() ).fail();`  That should allow each call to operate independently of the other (assuming they don't depend on each other).  Say one call returns data quickly, but takes a while to process - this way the processing can being just as soon as the data is returned.

Comment: If you're looking for the quicker solution, then what I've put is it, for most situations, as the bottleneck will be getting your data over the network. When you chain them, each Ajax call only starts when the last one has finished. Doing it as above starts all the calls as soon as possible (within the constraint of the number of simultaneous http connections your browser will allow). Try both and see which is quicker for you over a network.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out BreezeJS. It has an option to make a single Ajax call to pull multiple lookups.

Take a look at the BreezeJS docs for a detailed explanation: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/lookup-lists